# Adding multiple css properties to simple modal

Tags: jquery, css, simplemodal

How can I apply multiple CSS properties in `overlayCss` to the simple modal(aside from the `backgroundColor` property)? I've tried separating properties with a comma, but that breaks the functionality.

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body'),
        overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"},
        overlayClose:true, 
    });
    // Set overlay's width
    $(window.parent.document).find('#basic-modal-content').css('width', "100%");

    return false;
});
```

Comment: Couldn't you just add a class that contains the CSS properties you'd like, then it would apply to the modal?

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off using an actual css class to define multiple styles

```
 $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
    appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body'),
    overlayCss: 'myClass',
    overlayClose:true, 
});
```

Then in css

```
.myClass{
    [as many properties as you want here]
}
```

It will make your code much easier to maintain and extend

Answer (score 0):

You need the [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

```
$('#basic-modal .basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal({
        appendTo: $(window.parent.document).find('body').css({
            opacity: 1.0,
            backgroundColor: "black"
        }),
        //overlayCss: {backgroundColor:"#000"},
        overlayClose:true, 
    }).css({
     'opacity' : 0.8,
     'position': 'absolute',
     'top': 0,
     'left': 0,
     'background-color': 'black',
     'width': '100%'
  });
    // Set overlay's width
    $(window.parent.document).find('#basic-modal-content').css('width', "100%");

    return false;
})
```